# What's the best way to parse a map in clojure when using clj.http?

Tags: parsing, clojure, maps, clj-http

I have a map like so

```
(client/post "http://localhost:5000" {:form-params {:new {:title "some-title" :description "some-description"}}})
```

In the server, I have the following:

```
(get-in request [:form-params "new"])
```

Which gives me the following:

```
"{:title \"some-title\", :description \"some-description\"}"
```

A string and not an actual map. Using the Cheshire library's `parse-string` gives the ": unexpected" error. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have not accepted a single answer since Nov '19.  May I be so bold and ask why?

Answer (score 1):

Add `:content-type :application/edn` to your request map, to parse EDN.  Add `:as :auto, :coerce :always` to do the coercion automatically.

Comment: Doing ```(client/post "http://localhost:5000" {:form-params {:new {:title "some-title" :description "some-description"} :content-type :application/edn :as auto :coerce :always}})``` makes the params and form-params disappear when the request comes into the server.